# background image need to fit the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which size may differ time to time.

At I set a background image to tat div which image size is fixed.
But I need to fit the background image to div at any size.

How could be possible thro' CSS.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to change a size of an image with CSS is when it's an `<img>` element.
I mean that you can do something like that:

```
img#myBG { width:200px; height:100px; }
```

If you need it to be a background, you should use 'z-index' and put your `img` under a the element that holds the content.

Something like this:

```
<div id="holder">
  <img id="myBG" src="...." />
  <div>my content here</div>
</div>

<style>
#holder { position:relative; width:200px; height:100px; }
#holder div { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:2; }
img#myBG { width:200px; height:100px;  { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1;  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with CSS 2.x that's available in most browsers, but CSS 3 has introduced the `background-size` property. You can read details here: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/